# input data in a view and passing it to controller(asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently on *Homecontroller's* index view page. I have a Google map there. I have defined a *model* called *events* which stores **events based on their latitude and longitude**.

Now what I want to do is whenever a user clicks on map, I use google's API to get latitude and longitude and make the user fill other details of the event and then invoke the *create()* method in EventsController(Events is my database name) to insert this event into the table. But as views can't invoke controller's methods, I am stuck.

Is there any other way to do this. Thanks in advance.